# How to reach a common number by adding a number k, to an array of numbers arr[]?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, math, lcm

I am stuck with an algorithm problem since days. 
If we have an array of numbers, lets say, arr[2,4,9] and a var k, lets say k=7.

Is there a common number possible which can be reached by adding k to each of the elements inside the arr[] ?

### EDIT:

---

WHen i say common number i mean a number X=(n<sub>i</sub>k*arr[i]) 
where n is a positive integer which could be different for each i, k is a positive integer provided to us, arr is the array of numbers.
So it is basically to find an n for which n<sub>i</sub>k*arr[i] = a common number for all i.

---

I had a hunch of using LCM concept here but was not able to figure out the algorithim all the way through. A lead will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Could you clarify your question?

Comment: Clearly adding `k` to each of the elements in the array `arr` would yield `9, 11, 16` which is possible (but I don't think that's what you mean)... what result would you like?

Comment: No, it is not possible, even if you add different multiples of `7` to each element.

Comment: What you mean by " common number"?

Comment: Question in the last part , "we have to add a variable K" to make elements of array equal, i think it needs more clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can add multiples of `k` to each element, then each element of the array can take on a value of the form

```
value := arr[i] + j * k
```

for some integer value `j`. Thus, they can only obtain the same value if all elements are initially some multiple of `k` difference from each other.

Alternatively, you can view this problem in terms of modular arithmetic. Only if all elements reduce to the same value modulo k will you be able to obtain a common value between them by adding multiples of `k`

```
forall e in arr ->  e mod k == c; for some constant c
```

Comment: That is too wary imo. OP asked a variable K and not its multiple. The Question is really absurd and needs more clarification.

Comment: If we interpreted OP's question literally, if would be equivalent to asking if for array `[a, b, c]`, are `[a + k, b + k, c + k]` equal. I feel that OP's mention of LCM is enough to clarify that we can add `k` multiple times to each element.

Comment: Yeah, LCM is just fine, Appreciate your response :)

Comment: @Dillin You are correct sir. We can indeed have multiples of k. Edits provided.

Answer (score 0):

Super easy.

```
    List<Integer> l = Arrays.asList(1, 6, 11);
    int k = 5;

    int min = l.stream().mapToInt(x -> x).min().getAsInt();
    boolean result = l.stream().mapToInt(x -> x)
            .map(x -> x - min)
            .allMatch(x -> x % k == 0);

    System.out.println("result = " + result);
```